# Blender won't open, only flashes command prompt

Tags: error

I was working on a project, but decided to install a windows update, specifically the January 3, 2018 update. Now when I try to open Blender, only a command prompt flashes and nothing happens.

I tried installing, reinstalling as well as running through the system files instead of the desktop icon. I've looked all over the web, but can't find a solution.

Comment: Can you check your graphics driver and see if it updated, over here I had to roll back to the last driver before when this happened.

Comment: i have an AMD Radeon Rx580, and blender worked on an older driver before the windows update. I recently updated it after Blender stopped working, and Blender still won't work.

Comment: I GOT IT TO WORK. I updated my intel graphics card as well as my firmware.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a second graphics card, try to update that as well as update your firmware. Instead of going to windows and searching for an update there, go to Windows Drivers and manually update everything you can.